# Azure Resource Manager IP Security Restrictions using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to use Powershell to set IP Security Restrictions. My syntax is not returning any errors, but settings are not changing. The "ipSecurityRestrictions" property is a hashtable.

```
$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName *resource-group-name* -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01
$p = $r.Properties
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions = @{ ipAddress = "0.0.0.0"; subnetMask = "0.0.0.0" }
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName *resource-group-name* -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -PropertyObject $p
```

It's not a permissions issue, and there are no errors returned.  To change a property that is not a hashtable, such as the phpVersion the following code is working fine:

```
$p.phpVersion = "7.0"
```

Anyone successfully set ipSecurityRestrictions using this method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ipSecurityRestrictions` should  be object array. Please have a try to  change code as  following. It works correctly for me.

```
$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01

$p = $r.Properties
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions = @()
$restriction = @{}
$restriction.Add("ipAddress","0.0.0.0")
$restriction.Add("subnetMask","0.0.0.0")
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions+= $restriction

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -PropertyObject $p
```

[image]

After that we can get the result from the resources azure 
(https://resources.azure.com).

[image]

We also can get powershell cmd  from the resource azure.

[image]

Comment: How to do this for all the Slots in a Web App ?  IP restrictions are slot dependent..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convenience function to add a rule:

```
function Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # Name of the resource group that contains the App Service.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        $ResourceGroupName, 

        # Name of your Web or API App.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        $AppServiceName, 

        # rule to add.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
        [PSCustomObject]$rule 
    )

    $ApiVersions = Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceTypes |
        Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq 'sites' |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty ApiVersions

    $LatestApiVersion = $ApiVersions[0]

    $WebAppConfig = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' -ResourceName $AppServiceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion

    $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions =  $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions + @($rule) | 
        Group-Object name | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Last 1 }

    Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $WebAppConfig.ResourceId -Properties $WebAppConfig.Properties -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion -Force    
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
# determine current ip
$clientIp = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.ipify.org' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content

$rule = [PSCustomObject]@{
    ipAddress = "$($clientIp)/32"
    action = "Allow"  
    priority = 123 
    name = '{0}_{1}' -f $env:computername, $env:USERNAME 
    description = "Automatically added ip restriction"
}

Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -AppServiceName "myAppServiceName" -rule $rule
```

Source: [Configure Azure App Service IP Restrictions using PowerShell](https://about-azure.com/2018/11/26/configure-azure-app-service-ip-restrictions-using-powershell/)