# Modify Azure AppService ipsecurity during release from VSTS

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, release, whitelist

I am trying to add new ip addresses to the whitelist of Azure AppService. I am unable to use XML Transformation or simply replace tokens as the needed list of new entries will be obtained in the beginning of the release and not before. I am also unable to modify the content of the zipped site (published with /p:DeployOnBuild=True). The deployment is done using "Azure App Service Deploy" task. I know of `Set-AzureRMWebApp` cmdlet but it only allows to modify the appSettings and connectionStrings sections. It there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Set-AzureRMResource PowerShell command:

```
$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01

$p = $r.Properties
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions = @()
$restriction = @{}
$restriction.Add("ipAddress","0.0.0.0")
$restriction.Add("subnetMask","0.0.0.0")
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions+= $restriction

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -PropertyObject $p
```

A Related thread: [Azure Resource Manager IP Security Restrictions using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477518/azure-resource-manager-ip-security-restrictions-using-powershell?answertab=active#tab-top)

Another way is that you can publish project with FileSystem method:

Some Build Tasks:

1. Visual Studio Build (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish`)
2. Publish Build Artifacts (Path to Publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory))

Release Tasks:

1. [Replace token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) or Other tasks to update web.config (Could use [File Transform & Variable Substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution) in Azure App Service Deploy task)
2. Azure App Service Deploy (1. Uncheck Publish using WebDeloy option 2. Package or folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Comment: This approach has a drawback where it only works for post-deployment scenario.

Comment: @juvchan What do you mean post-deployment scenario? What's the detail scenario?

Comment: In my case I am trying to add new entries to the web.config file. I can see this approach working but on the resource level which is not something I can go with.

Comment: @Quass1m You could publish web project with FileSystem method (Check the update of my answer)

Comment: I currently use "Azure App Service Deploy" task in VSTS. I don't think you can you it to deploy from something different than a package. Do you know of a workaround for this? Of course, zipping the application is a potential solution but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @Quass1m You can deploy the published files in a folder through Azure App Service Deploy task, just uncheck Publish Using WebDeploy option. You can try it and check the result.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Unchecking this option did in fact work but now I am unable to replace values in my web.config with the parameters.xml file (and SetParameters.xml is not being created in "File System" publish method). For a different reason I am unable to move all tokenized parameters to web.*.config and use transformations (workflow requirements). The "XML transformation" and "XML variable substitution" options don't help me. Thank you for your advice anyway since it may help others.

Comment: @Quass1m Could you set the IP value in parameters.xml and SetParameters.xml files?

Comment: It's not possible in my workflow. I only know the full list of IP's to add in deploy time, not during build. The addresses point at build agents, test agents, load test agents etc. I am unable to use subnet mask or a range of public IP's since they are provided randomly. I found no way to add new ipSecurity entries by modifying the SetParametrs.xml file alone. The key point is also not to modify the zipped WebDeploy package file.

Comment: @Quass1m You can insert the element, check this blog: [Web Deploy XML File Parameterization](https://blogs.iis.net/elliotth/web-deploy-xml-file-parameterization), then change the value in SetParameters.xml file in release.

Comment: I have read this article before but did not notice that you can use msdeploy this way. With this I believe I can solve my issues. Thank you for all the help!