# Setting Azure function IP restrictions using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to modify the IP restrictions for my Azure function app using Azure PowerShell. I'm using the method described here: [Modify Azure AppService ipsecurity during release from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353542/modify-azure-appservice-ipsecurity-during-release-from-vsts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename -ApiVersion 2016-08-01

$p = $r.Properties
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions = @()
$restriction = @{}
$restriction.Add("ipAddress","0.0.0.0")
$restriction.Add("subnetMask","0.0.0.0")
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions+= $restriction

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName resourcename -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -PropertyObject $p -Force
```

However the Set-AzureRmResource CmdLet fails with error:

`The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Resource Manager IP Security Restrictions using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477518/azure-resource-manager-ip-security-restrictions-using-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you using for your `resourcename`? It should be `yourFunctionAppName/web`

Your commands work exactly as is for me replacing `Resoucegroup name` with my resourceGroup name, and `resourcename` with `my-function-app-name/web`