# Bulk edit whitelisted IP Addresses

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have a lot of IP addresses to add and remove and doing it via the portal is painful (well, boring).

Can I use the CLI to add/remove IP addresses to/from a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible yet. Microsoft has been promising this for a while.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/32151361-allow-azure-app-service-ip-restriction-configurati

Answer (score 1):

> I have a lot of IP addresses to add and remove and doing it via the portal is painful (well, boring).

We could edit the ipSecurityRestrictions with CLI command or azure resource(https://resources.azure.com/). You also could the CLI command from it directly.

```
az resource update --id /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{websitename}/config/web --api-version 2016-08-01 --set properties.key=value
```

[image]

I did a demo with powershell command before, you could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477518/azure-resource-manager-ip-security-restrictions-using-powershell/41502686#41502686).

Comment: You could operation it directly with azure resource that I mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any updates to share yet on timeline, but will update the User Voice feature request when there is anything to share.